# Opening another form in mfc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I need to close the current form dialog and open another form after the user clicks a button in an mfc application. Basically it is for my school project application.
I have decided use mfc in visual c++ for my project and i have obsolutely no guidance regarding the language.
I had chosen single document  and CFormView class in mfc application wizard and used the resource editor to design two forms one of them is displayed at start of program and i need the other to open up and replace existing form.
Had tried googling for an answer but couldn't understand anything. I have basic c++ oop knowledge but i am completely new to mfc.
I use visual studio 2013 ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't close current dialog truely, you can just hide it. So to do like this:

```
CCurrentDialig::OnBtnCliekted()
{
ShowWindow(this->m_hWnd, SW_HIDE);
COtherDialog dlg;
dlg.DoModal();
}
```

Comment: I created a button click event from resource editor and it has definition:
void CIntefacedesignView::OnBnClickedButton11() {....}
I then entered the code you suggested .
void CIntefacedesignView::OnBnClickedButton11()
{
 // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
 ShowWindow(this->m_hWnd, SW_HIDE);
 CFORMVIEW dlg;
 dlg.DoModal();
}
intellisense highlighted this SW_HIDE and CFORMVIEW as errors i dont know about the first two but i know there is no CFORMVIEW class please tell me where to declare it and how to declare it.

Comment: SW_HIDE is declared in Winuser.h.CFORMVIEW? maybe is CFormView, CFormView is declared in afxext.h.